# Distribution of linear combination of iid exponential rv

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d exp$(\lambda)$. How can I find the distribution of $U_n = \sum^n_{i=1} X_i/i$? Is this CF, MGF, PGF related? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, @AndréNicolas? The CF of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-nit}$, so I get that the CF of $U_n$ is $$\frac{\lambda^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\lambda-kit)}.$$

Comment: Ouch, I did not see the $i$ in the denominator.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Does that CF simplify to any common distribution? It is supposed to be equal to the distribution of $Y_n = $max{$X_1,...,X_n$} for which I got as exp $(n\lambda)$...I'm beginning to think this is wrong.

Comment: @qualVictim: yes, it is wrong. For istance, by following the lines below, we have that the distribution of $U_4$ when $\lambda=1$ is given by $$-\frac{e^{-x}}{6}+2 e^{-x/2}-\frac{9 e^{-x/3}}{2}+\frac{8 e^{-x/4}}{3}$$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @qualVictim: moreover, the distribution of $U_n$ cannot be $\exp(n\lambda)$, since $\mathbb{E}[U_n]=\lambda H_n\approx \lambda\log n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, since the CF of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-nit}$, the CF of $U_n$ is given by:
$$\frac{\lambda^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\lambda-kit)},\tag{1}$$
so its MGF is given by:
$$\frac{\lambda^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\lambda+kt\right)},\tag{2}$$
and its distribution is given by the inverse Fourier transform of $(1)$ that can be computed through the Residue theorem.